# How to make this symbol?

Tags: symbols

Those symbols to represent the moment "torque" in vector mechanics . I'm sure I saw that symbol in some book but I do not remember .

[image]

Comment: Notwithstanding the usefulness of learning how to make a new symbol, are you sure you want to use it? A descriptive symbol should be used to describe things that are semantically related. Even if you are not mistaken that you have truly seen this, torque is a force like any other, so you'll probably want to represent it as a regular vector, like `\vec{\tau}`, unless you have a clear reason to make a distinction.

Comment: @giusti The torque is a pseudovector, as it does not really behave like a vector. Moreover, it is only really a vector in three dimensions; in two dimensions it is a scalar and in higher dimensions a two-form. The distinction is justified, though not always needed.

Comment: Interesting, point taken! I have never seen such a distinction, though, so I'm genuinely curious. Can you show me a text where this symbol is used so I can understand the context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `\longrightarrow` is too much, but `\rightarrow` is too short.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\torquesymbol}{{%
  \vphantom{\circlearrowleft}%
  \mathpalette\torque@symbol\relax
}}
\newcommand{\mediumrightarrow}{\relbar\mathrel{\mkern-8mu}\rightarrow}
\newcommand\torque@symbol[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\circlearrowleft$\hidewidth\cr
    $\m@th#1\mkern2mu\mediumrightarrow$\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\torque}[1]{\overset{\torquesymbol}{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\torque{M}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% for convenience, you may define a new command:
\newcommand{\torque}[1]{\overset{\hspace{.5em}\circlearrowleft\hspace{-.9em}\longrightarrow}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    $\overset{\hspace{.5em}\circlearrowleft\hspace{-.9em}\longrightarrow}{M}$
    or with the command:
    $\torque{M}$
\end{document}
```

EDIT: of course you may define a specific new command (even if egreg says that `\longrightarrow` is too long, and he is always right!).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way to make the torque symbol is to use `\longrightarrow` and the `\leftturn` symbol from `wasysymb`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for \scalebox macro
\newcommand\torque{%
  \ooalign{
  \hss\scalebox{1}{$\leftturn$}\hss\cr%
  \hbox{\scalebox{1}{$\longrightarrow$}}}}
\begin{document}
Torque symbol
$\torque$\\
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]